# Button Style api 21

Tags: android, button, styles

I see the new animation of buttons on api 21:
[image: button animation api21 android]

But I want to do that with blue color, i see on another question to use this custom style in buttonstyle.xml (on Drawables folder):

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/Blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

But my min API is 14 and it crash because I need min 21 to use ripple, how I can make to if the user have android 5 can show this animation in blue and if the user has a lower version show the normal animation but also in blue?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no `ripple` in older API

Comment: but is there any option of have the 2 styles and the app choose one depending the api of the user?
Because now, with the default style in a Android 5 emulator y see THE API 21 EFFECTS and if I open the app in an Android 4.4 emulator I se the normal effects, so is possible to do that, I only want to change the colors. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable library!

buttonstyle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/Blue" >
    <!-- @color/Blue is ripple color -->
    <!-- item(id=mask): image which will be filled by ripple -->
    <item 
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <!-- default button background image -->
        <inset
            android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
            android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
                <!-- e0e0e0 is default backround color -->
                <!-- this solid element can be removed, but i dont test this -->
                <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
                <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
    <!-- item(none): default button background -->
    <item>
        <!-- default button background image -->
        <inset
            android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
            android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
                <!-- e0e0e0 is default backround color -->
                <solid android:color="#e0e0e0" />
                <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Activity:

```
//button is your button
button.setBackgroundDrawable(LollipopDrawablesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.buttonstyle, getTheme()));
button.setOnTouchListener(new DrawableHotspotTouch((LollipopDrawable) button.getBackground()));
```

works! https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzI04.png